# IIS rewrite: rewrite URL's from directory to other domain

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

I want all request that look like:

```
(www.)mydomain.com/belgium(/*)
```

to be redirected to:

```
(www.)mydomain.be
```

The path and querystring after `/belgium/` need to be included:

```
www.mydomain.com/belgium/page1/page11?filter=yes
```

Needs to become

```
www.mydomain.be/page1/page11?filter=yes
```

Comment: And what doesn't work with your current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="Rewrite" enabled="true">
      <match url="www.mydomain.com/belgium" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
         <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.+)"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.mydomain.be?{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>

     <rule name="Rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url="www.mydomain.com/belgium/{.*)" />  
    <action type="Redirect" url="www.mydomain.be{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

You can write additional rule to handle `www` part of the link.
I write this out of my head so it is not correct but I believe it should give you a hint.